# match all parameters in all options then query the database

Tags: php, mysql

sorry if that title is vague I can't even think of what to call what I am trying to do...will update given comments.

I have two sets of checkboxes the first (called code) set has 5 options and then second set has 20 options (called family). Currently in order to construct a WHERE statements for my query I do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST['code'])){ 
foreach($_POST['code'] as $key=>$value){ 
    if($value==1) $criteria[] = "code='".mysql_escape_string($key)."'"; 
} 
 $criteria = implode(' OR ', $criteria);
}

if(isset($_POST['family']) && !empty($_POST['family'])){ 
foreach($_POST['family'] as $key=>$value){ 
    if($value==1) $family_criteria[] = "family='".mysql_escape_string($key)."'";

} 
$family_criteria = implode(' OR ', $family_criteria);

}
```

and here is part of the query

```
WHERE $criteria AND $family_criteria ORDER BY ....
```

this results in "WHERE code=1 OR code=2 AND family=jones ORDER BY..."

while what I need it to do is "WHERE code=1 and family=jones OR code=2 and family=jones ORDER BY..."

Comment: Wrap each block of OR criteria in parentheses. `(code=1 OR code=2) AND (family=jones)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about constructing the following:

```
... WHERE (code=1 or code=2) and family='jones' ...
```

This will require only a minor adjustment to the  to add the parens around the `code` parameter generation, and is semantically identical to what you said you want.

```
if(isset($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST['code'])){ 
    foreach($_POST['code'] as $key=>$value){ 
        if($value==1) $criteria[] = "code='".mysql_escape_string($key)."'"; 
    } 
    $criteria = "(" . implode(' OR ', $criteria) . ")";
}
```

Comment: wow, I was thinking way off...that is such an easy fix thank you so much!

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping the family part, too, else you'll end up with `(code=1 or code=2) and family=jones or family=smith`, which won't evaluate correctly.